# comparative meaning of sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context

*"They climbed mountains and  braved **through** the seas"*

*"these six men braved the rough seas"*

My question is,  does "***through***" make any difference in the meaning between these two sentence? If yes,  what sense does it add to the meaning of the second sentence compared to the first?

Comment: Including ***through*** wouldn't change the meaning (what feasible alternatives could there be?), but ***to brave through*** (or *brave **across, along, over,*** etc.) is not an idiomatic usage in English.

Comment: just to be sure,  both mean "face sort of difficulties  fearlessly  while  crossing a sea  on a  boat or ship ?dont they?

Comment: Well, transitive *to brave [something]* literally just means to be brave when faced with *something* that might be expected to frighten you or make you run away. You can infer that braving rough seas might imply fearlessly *crossing* them, but in another context it might just mean being brave enough to stand on the end of a pier during a storm, fearless of or oblivious to the danger of being washed out to sea by a freak wave.

Comment: Although I did actually mention the fact of it being a transitive verb, I think StoneyB's answer more explicitly flags up the relevance of that point. It needs to be followed by an *object*, being ***the thing*** that is bravely confronted, not just some adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 4):

In Present-Day English the verb *brave* is used transitively only. It requires a direct object which represents the danger confronted, or its source, and you cannot make that object the oblique of a preposition. Consequently, *They braved **through** the seas* is ungrammatical.

There is an obsolete intransitive sense, but it has a very different meaning: to "boast" or "brag".

Comment: OED has ***to brave it*** twice (as *To swagger, act the bravo*, and *To dress splendidly, to make a gay show*), both of which seem somewhat archaic/obsolete to me. But there are hundreds of written instances of [***I braved it***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+braved+it%22) where "it" doesn't necessarily have any obvious referent (i.e. - it looks like a "dummy"). And they seem perfectly idiomatic to me today, as the opposite of ***I bottled it*** (again, something of a "dummy it" usage).

Comment: Indeed, @FumbleFingers. So "I braved it through the seas" would be fine. The verb would be transitive, so it would work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What Google actually shows me there is about a dozen instances. In many the *it* does have an explicit reference; one is the obsolete use (Walter Scott). The rest are all very recent, and the *it* seems to be not a dummy but a sort of generic reference to the situation, as when we say *tough it out* or *suck it up*. (I don't know *bottled it*.) In any case, whether the object's a dummy or not, it's still a transitive use.

Comment: @Colin Fine: A slightly odd thing to say, but in principle yeah. I'd certainly have no problem with an agoraphobic saying *I'm really proud of myself! I braved it down to the shops this afternoon!*

Comment: @StoneyB: I think to bottle it is Cockney rhyming slang originating in bottles of Courage light ale (doubtless a British brand that you'd never have heard of). Well, I'd *like* to think that, but I don't dare google it because somewhere in the back of my mind I suspect that's just my fevered imagination on overdrive, and I don't want to lose all my treasured and carefully-hoarded folk etymologies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers why don't you post an answer including the citations of  "I braved it..."?

Comment: Michael Quinion [suggests tentatively](http://worldwidewords.org/topicalwords/tw-bot1.htm) that it is rhyming slang, @FumbleFingers, but it's rather _bottle and glass_ = _class_. The noun _bottle_ certainly precedes the verbs _bottle (it)_ and _bottle out_.